# What causes the REQ socket to NOT recv replies from REP?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I implemented the [lazy pirate pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:chapter4#Client-Side-Reliability-Lazy-Pirate-Pattern) for my client module, which works great for retrying the requests. But here's the problem.

1. REQ Client sends message to REP server. [OK]
2. REP server interprets the message. [OK]
3. REP server executes some action, and prepares the response. [OK]
4. REP server sends back the response. [OK]
5. REQ Clients polls message but doesn't receive any until it timeout. [NOT OK]
6. REQ Client restarts the socket, and retries to send the request again. [NOT OK]
7. REP Server executes the action again. [THE PROBLEM]
8. This time REQ Client successfully receives the response. [OK]

That's the problem, I'm executing the action twice which was intended to be only executed once. I think this is the best way I could explain it.

In certain occasions client can send simultaneously send request to server as I have a coroutine running on a thread, separated from the main thread both of which has functionality that sends request to server. Could this be the cause of it?

I also have multiple of these clients connected to the server, could this be the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q1** : *"Could this* <sub>... coroutine based co-existence ...</sub> *be the cause of it?"*

Yes, mostly if coroutines use the same instance of the **`REQ`**-archetype.

> **Q2** : *"... could this* <sub>... multiple of these clients **connected** to the server ...</sub> *be the problem?"*

No, given each client operates on it's own instance of a **`REQ`**-archetype, connected towards the **`REP`**-(server)-side, there ought be no reason to imminent blocks ( for details, read more about the **`REQ/REP`** principal certainty to fall into an un-salvagable mutual dead-lock, where the only thing you cannot know is, when it will happen, but we all may be sure, it will happen )

---

If an atomic, singleton-alike unique executions are needed ( and if server implementation permits that ), one may log each **`REQ`**'s task-`{UUID}`, to prevent double-shots onto the same task-target.

There is hardly to tell more, without the actual MCVE / MWE-representation of the problem ( the **`.poll`**-ing loop logic / timeout / remedy-strategies ).